# Spring boot Multiple Starter's

Tags: spring-boot

I am starting development on a new spring boot app. Although I have had prior experience in working with boot, but this time we have been instructed to build the app by just using boot starters.

The technical stack is as follows:

1. Spring MVC
2. Spring Security
3. Log4j2
4. Eclipse Link
5. Maven

App running on weblogic. 
...... Etc

So I was wondering if it's ok to use multiple boot starters in a single app?

If yes then from the looks of it I might have to use around 4 starters to get where I want to be.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

You can build your app with any number of starters, with some restrictions i guess... you probably don't want to use tomcat and undertow starter in the same project for example :)

A starter includes dependencies for the given starter type along with auto-configuration to get you up and running in no time. You can [read more here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-starter) on starters.

Edit:
some useful info on [weblogic deployment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-weblogic), [configuring log4j2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging) and [eclipselink](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/eclipselink) in spring-boot

[This project](http://start.spring.io/starter.zip?type=maven-project&bootVersion=1.5.3.RELEASE&baseDir=demo&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&packaging=war&javaVersion=1.8&language=java&autocomplete=&generate-project=&style=security&style=web&style=data-jpa) should get you started with sufficient dependencies. (from start.spring.io)